# iter_rows() not from first row

Tags: python, loops

I'm iterating through a dataset with `.iter_rows()` :

```
for row in dataset.iter_rows():
    print row
    print
```

For a reason that isn't relevant to the question, I'd like to skip the first 20 rows, for instance. Is this possible in a cleaner way than this trick ?

```
skip = 20
i = 0
for row in dataset.iter_rows():
    i += 1
    if i <= skip:
        continue
    print row
    print
```

Comment: If this is an openpyxl `iter_rows()` method, then the `row_offset` would definitely be the best option. If not, then `islice()`. And let us know if it was mistakenly closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

> Make an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable. *If `start` is non-zero, then elements from the iterable are skipped until `start` is reached*.

```
from itertools import islice

for row in islice(dataset.iter_rows(), 20):
    # ...
```